# ejabberd and JWT

Tags: jwt, ejabberd

I've been pounding at this for over a month following these:
https://www.process-one.net/blog/ejabberd-19-08/
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/authentication/#jwt-authentication

I've also been looking at posts like this one:
[JWT secret to use with ejabberd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490726/jwt-secret-to-use-with-ejabberd/62068751#62068751)

I've tried decoding the "k" value in the generated jwk to sign the Token. Nothing is currently working. I'm not exactly sure what the log is telling me, for all I know its missing the module responsible for JWT authentication.
my distribution is Garuda:Arch
ejabberd: 21.07-1

I get a crashlog:

```
2021-10-28 08:45:10.146309-05:00 [error] <0.674.0> ** Generic server <0.674.0> terminating                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 ** Last message in was {'$gen_event',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                         {xmlstreamelement,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                          {xmlel,<<"auth">>,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                           [{<<"xmlns">>,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                             <<"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">>},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                            {<<"mechanism">>,<<"PLAIN">>}],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                           [{xmlcdata,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                             <<"AGVyaWMAZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5SnFhV1FpT2lKbGNtbGpRR3h2ZDJWa2IzZHVMblJySWl3aVpYaHdJam94TmpNMU5ETXdPVEF4ZlEuSUY0LTI4ME9hU1h5Tjl6Yl9jZkZiQk9jWjNEZTMzOV9Xa2JPUkRlbm0tQQ==">>}]}}}                                                                               
 ** When Server state == #{mgmt_queue_type => ram,stream_header_sent => true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                           mgmt_state => inactive,tls_verify => false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                           stream_compressed => false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                           stream_timeout => {30000,-576458460293},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                           mgmt_stanzas_req => 0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                           codec_options => [ignore_els],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                           socket_monitor => #Ref<0.687724880.2890924033.7168>,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                           user => <<>>,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                           pres_a => {0,nil},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                           tls_options => [compression_none],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                           stream_state => wait_for_sasl_request,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                           xmlns => <<"jabber:client">>,shaper => c2s_shaper,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                           tls_required => false,stream_direction => in,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                           mgmt_max_queue => 5000,csi_state => active,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                           socket =>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                               {socket_state,ejabberd_http_ws,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                   {http_ws,<0.673.0>,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                       {{0,0,0,0,0,65535,32512,1},52662}},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                   262144,undefined,none,none},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                           server => <<"**SECURED.COM**">>,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                           csi_queue => {0,#{}},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                           lang => <<"en">>,access => c2s,mod => ejabberd_c2s,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                           tls_enabled => false,lserver => <<"**SECURED.COM**">>,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                           owner => <0.674.0>,mgmt_stanzas_in => 0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                           stream_authenticated => false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                           mgmt_max_timeout => 10800000,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                           stream_restarted => false,mgmt_ack_timeout => 60000,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                           zlib => false,resource => <<>>,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                           mgmt_resend => if_offline,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                           ip => {{0,0,0,0,0,65535,32512,1},52662},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                           stream_id => <<"9071053646738984762">>,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                           mgmt_timeout => 10800000,stream_encrypted => false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                           stream_version => {1,0},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                           mgmt_stanzas_out => 0}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 ** Reason for termination ==                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 ** {'function not exported',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        [{crypto,hmac,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
             [sha256,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
              <<229,202,17,249,237,157,59,64,236,115,50,234,213,255,52,31,109,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                41,169,46,98,176,188,245,108,155,161,54,88,230,126,175,76,111,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                17,186,156,41,53,27,223,122,164,116,89,189,150,4,207,251,152,85,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                18,80,49,19,137,243,49,205,5,134,110,182>>,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
              <<"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqaWQiOiJlcmljQGxvd2Vkb3duLnRrIiwiZXhwIjoxNjM1NDMwOTAxfQ">>],                                                                                                                                                                                                      
             []},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
         {jose_jwk_kty_oct,verify,4,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
             [{file,"src/jose_jwk_kty_oct.erl"},{line,159}]},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
         {jose_jws,verify,2,[{file,"src/jose_jws.erl"},{line,379}]},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
         {jose_jwt,verify,2,[{file,"src/jose_jwt.erl"},{line,189}]},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
         {ejabberd_auth_jwt,check_jwt_token,3,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
             [{file,"src/ejabberd_auth_jwt.erl"},{line,117}]},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
         {ejabberd_auth_jwt,check_password,4,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
             [{file,"src/ejabberd_auth_jwt.erl"},{line,76}]},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
         {ejabberd_auth,db_check_password,7,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
             [{file,"src/ejabberd_auth.erl"},{line,691}]},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
         {ejabberd_auth,'-check_password_with_authmodule/6-fun-0-',8,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
             [{file,"src/ejabberd_auth.erl"},{line,248}]}]}
```

My tokens are manually generated on jwt.io and key file is generated using mkjwk.org.
I'm fully aware that I am probably missing something stupid, but like I previously stated, I've been pounding at this for quite some time, its time to ask for help.

Comment: Thank you, @jps for cleaning up my post. If there is more info that could clarify what is going on, I will gladly post it. I'm getting ready to edit this post to include my ejabberd version and linux distribution just in case there is a problem with that specific build.

Comment: what do you need the k claim for?